# How do I enabling jQuery code assist in Notepad++

Tags: jquery, notepad++, code-completion

I have recently downloaded Notepad++ and am at loss on how to enable code assist for JQuery/JQueryUI on it.

Any tips and directions?

Comment: I was also looking for jQuery code hinting in Notepad++, couldn't find anything, so wrote the plugin myself: http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/11/26/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/

Comment: http://www.jamesallardice.com/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/
Define a user language for jquery here is a link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, Notepad++ has code assistance for languages, not frameworks. For jQuery you should set the language to Javascript. From the menu, navigate to:

> Language => J => Javascript

I believe that Notepad++ should also be smart enough to automatically do this if you open a .js file.

Comment: it is automatically activated.
under languages you fill find user defined. check the net if you find any files that you can import

Answer (score 5):

Language pack for jQuery Is available on github [here](https://github.com/jamesallardice/notepadplus-jQuery)

for detail installation of jQuery auto complete in notepad++ you can read [jquery auto complete in notepad++](http://buffernow.com/jquery-auto-complete-notepad/)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, and I think the questioner too :) THanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a handy code completion plugin for Notepad++ called [QuickText.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quicktext/)
It is very simple to use and can be utilized for any language that Notepad++ supports including Javascript(jQuery).

-Good Luck

Comment: I now realize that this may not actually be code completion but rather something like tab triggers.

Answer (score -1):

Also, switch to *"View As List"* in Function List (Windows shortcut *Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L*), and you can show/hide functions from the menu "*Plugins > Function List > Show All Functions*" (Notepad++ 5.7)